# What is the explanation of the network flags in MacOSX?

Tags: networking, mac, netstat, bsd

Good morning.

Could someone explain to me the meaning of the flags in the routing table?

For example if you check the output of `netstat -nr` you will have lines like this:

```
default            192.168.2.1        UGSc           56        3     en0
```

So this route for example has `UGSc` as flags.

The complete list of flags should be the following:

```
1   RTF_PROTO1  Protocol specific routing flag #1
2   RTF_PROTO2  Protocol specific routing flag #2
3   RTF_PROTO3  Protocol specific routing flag #3
B   RTF_BLACKHOLE   Just discard pkts (during updates)
b   RTF_BROADCAST   The route represents a broadcast address
C   RTF_CLONING     Generate new routes on use
c   RTF_PRCLONING   Protocol-specified generate new routes on use
D   RTF_DYNAMIC     Created dynamically (by redirect)
G   RTF_GATEWAY     Destination requires forwarding by intermediary
H   RTF_HOST    Host entry (net otherwise)
L   RTF_LLINFO  Valid protocol to link address translation
M   RTF_MODIFIED    Modified dynamically (by redirect)
R   RTF_REJECT  Host or net unreachable
S   RTF_STATIC  Manually added
U   RTF_UP  Route usable
W   RTF_WASCLONED   Route was generated as a result of cloning
X   RTF_XRESOLVE    External daemon translates proto to link address
Y   RTF_PROXY     Proxying; cloned routes will not be scoped
```

Well, some of them are easy to understand, other are more obscure to me...

Can someone eplain me what they mean please?
Thanks very much

Comment: An alternative description of some of those: https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1155586/html/GUID-07F1F043-7AB7-4749-8F8D-727929233E62.html

Comment: thanks. To be honest, what is more obscure to me are the RTF_PROTOx flags...and the difference between RTF_CLONING and RTF_PRCLONING

Comment: a partial explanation I found is here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19048-01/chorus5/806-7026/6jfu81m4m/index.html#ROUTING